# Parse error in Google Tag Manager script in XML Package

Tags: asp.net, xml, xml-parsing, google-tag-manager, aspdotnetstorefront

I have a webstore, running ASPDOTNETSTOREFRONT.

I'm trying to add a custom line of tracking script to a set of webpages.

To do this, i'm adding a Google Tag Manager script to the XML package that these pages use, so it appears on all the pages I want to track.

I've simply copied and pasted the Google Tag Manager script into my XML package.

```
`<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-5HD6WH"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-5HD6WH');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->`
```

But when I try to load a page using this package, it gives the following error.

```
Exception=Error in XmlPackage(.Load), Package=[product.engineproduct.xml.config], Msg=[Exception=An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 246, position 42.
]
```

So people can see the line numbers and position, I can show a screenshot from the XML package (source code).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJ2Tb.jpg

Anyone have any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the script contents in CDATA:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-5HD6WH"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>
<![CDATA[
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-5HD6WH');
]]>
</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Comment: how does this answer not have hundreds of up votes? Thank you very much dubloons!

Answer (score 1):

And 1 year later... I had the same problem in DNN 7.4.2.

I had something like this in httpdocs/SiteAnalytics.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AnalyticsEngineConfig>
    <Engines>
        <AnalyticsEngine>
            <EngineType>DotNetNuke.Services.Analytics.GoogleAnalyticsEngine, DotNetNuke</EngineType>
            <ElementId>Head</ElementId>
            <InjectTop>False</InjectTop>
            <ScriptTemplate>

                <!-- Google Tag Manager -->

                <script type="text/javascript">

          (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
                new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
                'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
                })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','<Tracking ID>');

        </script>

        <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

                <!-- documented... we would like to disable it by now
        <![CDATA[     

                <script type="text/javascript">
                  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
                  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '[TRACKING_ID]']);
                  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
                  [PAGE_URL]

                  (function() {
                    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
                    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
                  })();
                </script>

          ]]>
          -->
            </ScriptTemplate>
        </AnalyticsEngine>
    </Engines>
</AnalyticsEngineConfig>
```

See, by know i am leaving this as a manual change (but, as i am seeing now I think it will be very easy to integrate new google tag manager with DNN functionality and menus).

The change @dubloons proposed doesn't work for me, so i did it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AnalyticsEngineConfig>
    <Engines>
        <AnalyticsEngine>
            <EngineType>DotNetNuke.Services.Analytics.GoogleAnalyticsEngine, DotNetNuke</EngineType>
            <ElementId>Head</ElementId>
            <InjectTop>False</InjectTop>
            <ScriptTemplate>

                <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
        <![CDATA[
                <script type="text/javascript">

          (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
                new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
                'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
                })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','<Tracking ID>');

        </script>
        ]]>
        <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

                <!-- documented... we would like to disable it by now
        <![CDATA[     

                <script type="text/javascript">
                  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
                  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '[TRACKING_ID]']);
                  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
                  [PAGE_URL]

                  (function() {
                    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
                    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
                  })();
                </script>

          ]]>
          -->
            </ScriptTemplate>
        </AnalyticsEngine>
    </Engines>
</AnalyticsEngineConfig>
```

As you see, i sourrounded al script tag within CDATA, not just JS code.
 will be something like GTM-XXXXXX.
As you can see Tracking ID is hardcoded by know, but thats another issue ;D.